# How to copy a List<> to another List<> with Comparsion in c#

Tags: c#, .net, list, generics

I an having Two `Lists`. I want to get the matched and unmatched values based on **ID** and add the results to another `List`. I can get both of these using `Intersect/Except`.

But I can get only **ID** in the resultant variables (matches and unmatches) . I need all the properties in the Template.

```
List<Template> listForTemplate = new List<Template>();
List<Template1> listForTemplate1 = new List<Template1>();

 var matches = listForTemplate .Select(f => f.ID)
                      .Intersect(listForTemplate1 .Select(b => b.ID));

 var ummatches = listForTemplate .Select(f => f.ID)
                     .Except(listForTemplate1.Select(b => b.ID));

     public class Template
     {
       public string ID{ get; set; }
       public string Name{ get; set; }
       public string Age{ get; set; }
       public string Place{ get; set; }
       public string City{ get; set; }
       public string State{ get; set; }
       public string Country{ get; set; }
     }
     public class Template1
     {
         public string ID{ get; set; }
     }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to implement `IEquality` for this simple task, you can just modify your LINQ queries:

```
var matches = listForTemplate.Where(f => listForTemplate1.Any(b => b.ID == f.ID));
```

and

```
var unmatches = listForTemplate.Where(f => listForTemplate1.All(b => b.ID != f.ID));
```

You might want to check for null before accessing `ID`, but it should work.

Comment: I am getting only ID field( not all) for matches and unmatches
I need all properties.Any help!

Comment: If you want to compare against all properties then you will need to implement 'IEqualityComparer<T>'

Comment: I dont want to compare against all properties. Just compare with one property(ID) and get all properties in a another list

Comment: @user1612065 Those queries will return the entire object. Not just ID. If you add `.ToList()` to the end you can replace `var` with `List<Template>` and every `Template` will contain all values (Age, Name, ID, etc.).

Comment: Thanks..It works for matches case..I mean I can get what I am excepted.  But for unmatches case I get the unmatches list in both the List..I need Unmatches value in the listForTemplate1 only..Any help

Comment: @user1612065 Not sure what you mean but, in the unmatched you select all the items from `listForTemplate` that aren't in `listForTemplate1`. If you need them the other way around just exchange `listForTemplate1` and `listForTemplate` in the query.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the overloaded function, with the second parameter IEqualityComparer. So make your comparer ( example: http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/IEqualityComparer.aspx ), and use the same comparer in intersect / except.

And for the generic part: maybe you should have a common interface for templates e.g. ObjectWithID describing that the class have a string ID property. Or simply use dynamic in your comparer (but I think this is very-very antipattern because you can have run time errors if using for the bad type).

You also have a problem: intersecting two collections with two different types will result in a collection of Object (common parent class). Then you have to cast a lot (antipattern). I advise you to make a common abstract class/interface for your template classes, and it is working. If you need to cast the elements back, do not cast, but use the visitior pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern

Example (good):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16496998/how-to-copy-a-list-to-another-list-with-comparsion-in-c-sharp

        List<Template> listForTemplate = new Template[] {
            new Template(){ID = "1"},
            new Template(){ID = "2"},
            new Template(){ID = "3"},
            new Template(){ID = "4"},
            new Template(){ID = "5"},
            new Template(){ID = "6"},
        }.ToList();

        List<Template1> listForTemplate1 = new Template1[] {
            new Template1(){ID = "1"},
            new Template1(){ID = "3"},
            new Template1(){ID = "5"}
        }.ToList();

        var comp = new ObjectWithIDComparer();

        var matches = listForTemplate.Intersect(listForTemplate1, comp);
        var ummatches = listForTemplate.Except(listForTemplate1, comp);

        Console.WriteLine("Matches:");
        foreach (var item in matches) // note that item is instance of ObjectWithID
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", item.ID);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Ummatches:");
        foreach (var item in ummatches) // note that item is instance of ObjectWithID
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", item.ID);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}

public class ObjectWithIDComparer : IEqualityComparer<ObjectWithID>
{
    public bool Equals(ObjectWithID x, ObjectWithID y)
    {
        return x.ID == y.ID;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(ObjectWithID obj)
    {
        return obj.ID.GetHashCode();
    }
}

public interface ObjectWithID {
    string ID { get; set; }
}

public class Template : ObjectWithID
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
    public string Place { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
public class Template1 : ObjectWithID
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
Matches:
1
3
5

Ummatches:
2
4
6

Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Nice example, especially bringing it together with an interface.

Answer (score 1):

For comparison, this should also work (the first part is a variation on @MAV's answer):

```
var matches = from item in listForTemplate
              join id in listForTemplate1 on item.ID equals id.ID
              select item;

var unmatches = listForTemplate.Where(item => matches.All(elem => elem.ID != item.ID));
```

`matches` and `unmatches` will both be `IEnumerable<Template>` which is the type you require.

However, MAV's answer works fine so I'd go for that one.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, Implement the `IEqualityComparer<T>` interface.

[`IEqualityComparer<T>` MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Then use this as an argument in your method for `Except()` and `Intersect()`

[Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355408.aspx)

There is a good example of how to do so on the link for the `Intersect()` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't absolutely have to use LINQ, why not code something like this?

```
    var matches = new List<Template>();
    var unmatches = new List<Template>();

    foreach (var entry in listForTemplate)
    {
        bool matched = false;
        foreach (var t1Entry in listForTemplate1)
        {
            if (entry.ID == t1Entry.ID)
            {
                matches.Add(entry);
                matched = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!matched)
        {
            unmatches.Add(entry);
        }
    }
```

A disadvantage of the LINQ approach is that you're traversing the lists twice.